# Footables - Sort Indicator not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding, footable

I tried using sorting in Footables. It works fine except that the sort icon indicators in the header is not showing properly(it looks like a garbled character). It seems to be an encoding issue.

Here are the css that I included

```
footable.core.min.css
footable.metro.min.css
```

Here are the scripts that I included

```
footable.js
footable.filter.js
footable.paginate.js
footable.sort.js
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are 4 files in the FooTable-2\css\fonts directory:

- footable.eot
- footable.svg
- footable.ttf
- footable.woff

You need to add this folder and the files and the icons should appear